# Reading parquet files from different folders inside a azure storage container in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-blob-storage, parquet

I need to read parquet files from multiple directories inside a azure storage container..
for example,

```
Container1
 folder1
    parquet1
    parquet2
    ..
 folder2
   parquet5
   parquet6
   ...
```

I know these folders are virtual in blob but how do i read all these parquet and load into one dataframe.

```
paths=["wasbs://{container}@{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/pathToFile1","wasbs://{container}@{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net/pathToFile2"]
df=spark.read.parquet(*paths)
```

will the above code work?

Comment: This will not work. Technically, you're just iterating the items from the `paths` list. Having said that, it will create dataframe in both the cases. However, 2nd path would override the dataframe that you created in the 1st iteration. As dataframes are immutable objects you can't append the data to it. I would suggest create the dataframes separately and then do a `unionAll`. 
Also, I'm just curious if you are having same metadata in each of the folders why not keep them in one single folder, rather than creating overhead and adding more complexity to your code?